# Implementing bluetooth device connection in an Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, bluetooth

Im trying to implement the possibility to find and connect to bluetooth devices in my Angular project (v12.1.0) so i'm trying to install @manekinekko/angular-web-bluetooth.

But i'm getting the following error:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZObCr.png)

To me it seems that this package is not compatible with my angular version.

But is there a fix to this? Or are there any alternatives which i can use?

(Angular CLI: 12.1.0, Node: 14.17.0, npm 7.20.3)

Comment: Try `npm install @manekinekko/angular-web-bluetooth --force`

Comment: @KamranKhatti what does the flag do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday and was able to install by adding `--legacy-peer-deps` to the end of the install command.